# Is there a way I can initialize the value of an attribute of a django REST serializer based on the values of another field in the same serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
      owner=serializer.ReadOnlyField(source='auth.username')
      ownerUrl = .....
```

Say I have a serializer like so, with the create and update methods (not shown here), now what I want is the `ownerUrl` to take a value when a serializer is made, according to the `owner` value of the same serializer, how do I do this? 
for example is we make a serializer like so

```
serializer=MySerializer(MyModel.objects.get(pk=10))
```

then serializer.data.get('ownerUrl') has a value which is based on the value of  the `owner`, may be something like `<value of owner>+"/"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your serializer, You can do something like this:

```
 class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     owner=serializer.ReadOnlyField(source='auth.username')

     url = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

     def get_url(self, obj):
         ** obj is MyModel instance, so you can access model properties and return waht you need **
         return obj.username
```